# Display image based on data received over the internet for windows phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, mvvm

I request data over the internet and generally bind it in XAML.

Now I have difficulty accessing that received data, manipulate it and display it in user control.

```
    public partial class FullQuestionUserControl : UserControl
    {
         public FullQuestionUserControl()
         {
              InitializeComponent();
         }
    }
```

My model Questions contains fields such as id, authorFullName, text, containsImage.

This is how I bind:

```
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextSmall}" TextWrapping="Wrap"
        Text="{Binding SelectedQuestion.authorFullName}" />
```

I need to check containsImage. If true, then format a new string using id, and display it.

I know how to display the image:

```
    var bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(url));
    this.QuestionImage.Source = bi;
```

All I need is to get the Question in user control code.

How do I get the data in user control code?

Comment: You can do what you need using data binding rather than code-behind but your question is not very clear. If the containsImage property is true then you need to create the BitmapSource using a URL formatted including the id?

Answer (score 2):

This style will set the Image Source property when containsImage is true:

```
<Image>
    <Image.Resources>
        <stackoverflow:IdToImageSourceConverter x:Key="IdToImageSourceConverter"/>
    </Image.Resources>
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedQuestion.containsImage}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding SelectedQuestion.id, Converter={StaticResource IdToImageSourceConverter}}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

This converter will take the id property, format to the URL and return a BitmapImage for the image source:

```
class IdToImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var idValue = value.ToString();

        var url = string.Format("http://myurl.com/{0}", idValue);

        return new BitmapImage(new Uri(url));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I used converter, just like you suggested. Though, triggers, apparently, don't work in windows phone.